# transparent webview in ios not working

Tags: ios, webview, transparent

I am following the suggestions of some posts to make a webview transparent, but it still is opaque and white.  This code is from a plugin for unity3d that adds a webview in unity. Is there something about this code that would cause it not to be transparent?

https://github.com/gree/unity-webview

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    extern UIView *UnityGetGLView();

    extern UIViewController *UnityGetGLViewController();
    extern "C" void UnitySendMessage(const char *, const char *, const char *);
    extern UIWindow *_window;

    @interface WebViewPlugin : NSObject<UIWebViewDelegate>
    {
        UIWebView *webView;
        NSString *gameObjectName;
    }
    @end

    @implementation WebViewPlugin

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
     return YES;
    } 

    - (id)initWithGameObjectName:(const char *)gameObjectName_
    {
    self = [super init];

        UIView *view = UnityGetGLViewController().view;
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:view.frame];
        webView.delegate = self;
        webView.hidden = YES;
        webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO; 
        [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [webView setOpaque:NO];
        [view addSubview:webView];
        gameObjectName = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:gameObjectName_] retain];

        return self;    
    }
```

HTML/CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  font-size:12px;
//background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML looks like CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the plugin, and it should work well as far as I know.

Have you tried more simple HTML like this?

```
<body style="background-color: transparent;">
```

Comment: Oh. Thanks very much for building the plugin. It's great. I tried changing the hmtl and still no transparency. Any other things to try?

Comment: I think it's something in the html file in jquery that is setting it back to opaque. I took out all the jquery code and it is now transparent.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to make transparency work on the editor too?

Comment: Also I was wondering if there is a way to make clicks go through the webkit to the unity side. Apparently they are intercepted.

Comment: I never tried it. You might need to create WebView subclass and implement isOpaque method in WebView.m.

Comment: Override UIWebView -hitTest:withEvent: like http://stackoverflow.com/a/10149267/629118

Comment: Is there anything I can try from the unity side for the click through idea?

Comment: UIWebView covered up Unity CAEAGLLayer, so Unity can't get any touch events.